# Handling cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

I'm using berkshelf for handling my cookbook dependencies. In order to upload my cookbook on my server:

```
berks upload --force
```

1. Is this the best option?
2. Im trying to delete/remove this my cookbook form server. I'm not able to find any `berks remove/delete cookbook` command. I'm trying to use `knife delete cookbook`. I'm getting the next message:

> ERROR: Attempt to use relative path 'berk' when current directory is outside the repository path.
>   ERROR: Current working directory is 'D:/projects/living/vagrant/production/berk/berk'.

How could I handle it?

Comment: Has some command with `--force` ever been the best option? :D

Comment: Use `knife cookbook delete` to delete a cookbook from the Chef Server.

Answer (score 0):

Using force mode effectively disables the protections of frozen uploads, which is not recommended or we wouldn't have made it the default in Berkshelf. A frozen cookbook means that future uploads to the same version number will be prevented, ensuring that the contents of an uploaded cookbook won't change out from under you. In the bad old days before Test Kitchen, it was very common to have to upload to a development or staging Chef Server when testing cookbooks, so we didn't want to require a version bump every time for simplicity. Frozen mode is intended for "real" uploads, which is generally what Berks is doing.

As StephenKing points out, `knife cookbook delete` is the correct way to delete cookbooks but you should do this very infrequently. The error you mention is because your knife configuration is cranky at you.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger. Why do I need to use `berkshelf` for uploading the cookbook and I need to use `knife` to remove it?

Comment: I've been able to delete my cookbook from server. Nevertheless, I also would like to delete all its dependencies... Any ideas?

Comment: Because berks isn't a general purpose API tool and because recursive deletes are not common enough to have a dedicated tool for them.

Answer (score 0):

To manage version of my cookbooks I'm using build tool written in bash that wraps `knife` and `berks` commands in order to bootstrap and provision nodes. Part of this is tool is to update the cookbook version automatically and upload it to chef server.

```
v=`grep version cookbooks/$1/metadata.rb`
v=${v#*version}
v=${v#*\'}
v=${v%*\'}
echo $v
VERSION="${v%.*}.$((${v##*.}+1))"
echo $VERSION
sed "s/$v/$VERSION/g" cookbooks/$1/metadata.rb > output.txt
mv output.txt cookbooks/$1/metadata.rb
```

Then you pass ./version_updater.sh my_cookbook and you will have incremented version.